# Finding minimum of a set of recursion results

Tags: algorithm, proof, dafny

I am encoding the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) recurrence equation in Dafny.

I *think* I've got it verified, but I am curious if there's a more succinct way of representing the choice the recurrence takes among the three edit choices:

```
E(i,j) := min { 1 + E(i-1,j), 1 + E(i, j-1), diff(i, j) + E(i-1,j-1) }
```

In Dafny:

```
if 1 + recEdDist'(a, b, ai+1, bi) < 1 + recEdDist'(a, b, ai, bi+1) 
        && 1 + recEdDist'(a, b, ai+1, bi) < diff(a[ai], b[bi]) + recEdDist'(a, b, ai+1, bi+1)
then 1 + recEdDist'(a, b, ai+1, bi) else
if 1 + recEdDist'(a, b, ai, bi+1) < 1 + recEdDist'(a, b, ai+1, bi) 
        && 1 + recEdDist'(a, b, ai, bi+1) < diff(a[ai], b[bi]) + recEdDist'(a, b, ai+1, bi+1)
then 1 + recEdDist'(a, b, ai, bi+1) else
diff(a[ai], b[bi]) + recEdDist'(a, b, ai+1, bi+1)
```

Full [source here](https://gist.github.com/c-luu/ffa671b243124d5ad5dd43dfdd967893).

Answer (score 1):

If you define

```
function min(a: int, b: int) : int
{ if a < b then a else b }
```

the following expression gives the minimum of your three arguments:

```
min(1 + E(i-1,j), (min(1 + E(i, j-1), diff(i, j) + E(i-1,j-1))
```

and Dafny proves for you things like this, in case you would be worried:

```
  assert min(a, min(b, c)) <= a; 
  assert min(a, min(b, c)) <= b; 
  assert min(a, min(b, c)) <= c; 
  assert min(a, min(b, c)) == a || min(a, min(b, c)) == b || min(a, min(b, c)) ==c;
```

You say that you think you've got it verified. But what I see is a Dafny file with only a function definition and a few tests. What is verified is then only the well-definedness of the inductive function and these few test cases. Did you mean that by verification, or do you also have an implementation that is verified against this function?